# How do I using conditionals and stop function inside a function with vectors

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, purrr

I have a function that shifts the letters in the word based on random integer x. I need to set a conditional in the beginning that if x>list, the function will stop. I tried using the stop function but it produced an error.

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

library(purrr)

```
wordlist <- c("Is", "Book", "Appreciate", "Cherry", "Computer", "Of")

shift <- function(list, x){
  x <- sample(1:4,6, replace==TRUE)
  if (x>list) stop("length of x is greater than the letters in the word!")
  paste0(substr(list,nchar(list)-x+1,nchar(list)), substr(list,1,nchar(list)-x))
}

map(wordlist, shift)
```

For example, for the first two words "Of" and "Book", say x=3 for "Of" and x=2 for "Book", it will produce the following output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$result
NULL
[[1]]$error
<simpleError in .f(...): length of x is greater than the letters in the word!>

[[2]]
[[2]]$result
[1] "okbo"
[[2]]$error
NULL
```

Comment: You have two parameters in the `shift`

Comment: probably you should consider`if (any(x > nchar(list)))`

Comment: In your case you do not need a `stop` function but rather an `errorCondition` function

Answer (score 0):

What seems a bit confusing is where does `x` enter the picture. Is it a set of random numbers of length equal to the wordlist? Is it one random number shared by all members of the wordlist?

If `x` is different for each member of the wordlist, why don't you simply generate it inside the function?

For example:

```r
wordShift <- function(x) {
  # Set maximum value for shift location for each word
  nC <- nchar(x)
  # Now pick a random number between 1 and the value of nC for each element of
  # nC. Use vapply to do this relatively quickly and type-safely
  shiftLoc <- vapply(nC, sample, integer(1L), size = 1L)
  # Pre-allocate your results if you can. Return a vector like the input
  ret <- character(length(x))
  
  # Now loop through the list and rotate words
  for (i in seq_along(ret)) {
    ret[i] <- paste0(substr(x[i], shiftLoc[i], nC[i]),
                     substr(x[i], 1L, shiftLoc[i] - 1L))
  }
  ret
}
```

The above should never generate an illegal shifting location and uses `*apply` or naturally vectorized functions from base for speed and reliability without need for other packages. Here are some sample outputs:

```r
wordList <- c("Is", "Book", "Appreciate", "Cherry", "Computer", "Of")
set.seed(19L)
shifted <- t(replicate(25L, wordShift(wordList))) # transposing b/c replicated pastes columnwise

> shifted
      [,1] [,2]   [,3]         [,4]     [,5]       [,6]
 [1,] "Is" "ookB" "ciateAppre" "erryCh" "uterComp" "fO"
 [2,] "Is" "okBo" "Appreciate" "ryCher" "terCompu" "fO"
 [3,] "Is" "kBoo" "reciateApp" "ryCher" "puterCom" "Of"
 [4,] "Is" "okBo" "teApprecia" "erryCh" "rCompute" "fO"
 [5,] "Is" "Book" "reciateApp" "rryChe" "erComput" "Of"
 [6,] "sI" "ookB" "ciateAppre" "rryChe" "rCompute" "fO"
 [7,] "Is" "okBo" "ciateAppre" "erryCh" "uterComp" "Of"
 [8,] "Is" "Book" "teApprecia" "rryChe" "Computer" "fO"
 [9,] "Is" "Book" "eAppreciat" "herryC" "uterComp" "Of"
[10,] "sI" "kBoo" "preciateAp" "rryChe" "puterCom" "fO"
[11,] "sI" "kBoo" "eAppreciat" "erryCh" "rCompute" "fO"
[12,] "Is" "okBo" "reciateApp" "yCherr" "Computer" "fO"
[13,] "Is" "okBo" "eciateAppr" "Cherry" "puterCom" "fO"
[14,] "sI" "ookB" "teApprecia" "ryCher" "Computer" "Of"
[15,] "Is" "ookB" "eciateAppr" "Cherry" "erComput" "Of"
[16,] "sI" "kBoo" "ciateAppre" "yCherr" "mputerCo" "fO"
[17,] "Is" "Book" "ciateAppre" "rryChe" "terCompu" "Of"
[18,] "sI" "okBo" "ateAppreci" "rryChe" "puterCom" "fO"
[19,] "sI" "ookB" "teApprecia" "ryCher" "Computer" "Of"
[20,] "Is" "Book" "eciateAppr" "Cherry" "terCompu" "fO"
[21,] "Is" "okBo" "preciateAp" "erryCh" "mputerCo" "Of"
[22,] "sI" "kBoo" "eAppreciat" "rryChe" "rCompute" "fO"
[23,] "sI" "okBo" "ciateAppre" "Cherry" "erComput" "Of"
[24,] "sI" "okBo" "reciateApp" "Cherry" "omputerC" "fO"
[25,] "sI" "kBoo" "ciateAppre" "herryC" "omputerC" "Of"
```